# Couldn't update one table from the values of three tables (merging three into one)

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have below tables in mysql database

```
create table tbl_1(pid int, loc varchar(100), avaId int,xpId int,qf varchar(100));
create table tbl_2(soid int,pid int,sid int,name2 varchar(100), nrt2 int);
create table tbl_3(woid int,pid int,wid int,name3 varchar(100), nrt3 int);

create table tbl_sourcef(id int primary key auto_increment,pid int, loc varchar(100), avaId int,xpId int,qf varchar(100),sid int,nrt2 int,wid int,nrt3 int);
```

After inserting data into above tables

```
insert into tbl_1 values (1000,'Bangalore',30,9,'ABC');

insert into tbl_2 values(0,1000,1,'name1',8);
insert into tbl_2 values(1,1000,8,'name2',5);
insert into tbl_2 values(2,1000,7,'name3',6);

insert into tbl_3 values(0,1000,2,'D1',9);
insert into tbl_3 values(1,1000,1,'D2',2);
insert into tbl_3 values(2,1000,3,'D3',0);
insert into tbl_3 values(3,1000,4,'D4',5);
```

Below are the rows in above tbl_1,tbl_2,tbl_3

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am trying to merge these three tables into one table like this -

[image]

This is working correctly for one set of pid.. when I use another set of pid, it fails with subquery returned more than 1 row.. I couldn't find which is creating the problem

Am using a stored procedure named fupdate()

here is the definition of SP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fupdate(
pid int,loc varchar(100),avaId int,xpId int,qf varchar(100)
)
begin
        declare pi int Default 1;
        WHILE pi  <= 10 DO
            insert into tbl_sourcef(pid,loc,avaId,xpId,qf)values(pid,loc,avaId,xpId,qf);
            SET  pi = pi + 1;
        END WHILE;

     begin
              declare i int Default 1 ;
              declare si int default 0;
              declare es int;
              set es=(select count(sid) from tbl_2 where pid=pid);
                WHILE i  <= es DO
                    update tbl_sourcef ff
                    set ff.sid=(select sid from tbl_2 where soid=si and pid=pid),
                        ff.nrt2=(select nrt2 from tbl_2 where soid=si and pid=pid)
                    where id=i and pid=pid;
                    SET  i = i + 1;
                    SET si=si+1;
                END WHILE;
      end;
      begin
              declare wi int Default 1 ;
              declare wii int default 0;
              declare ew int;
              set ew=(select count(wid) from tbl_3 where pid=pid);
                WHILE wi  <= ew DO
                    update tbl_sourcef ff
                    set ff.wid=(select wid from tbl_3 where woid=wii and pid=pid ),
                        ff.nrt3=(select nrt3 from tbl_3 where woid=wii and pid=pid)
                    where id=wi and pid=pid ;
                    SET  wi = wi + 1;
                    SET wii=wii+1;
                END WHILE;
        end;

end
```

This is how am calling my SP -

```
call fupdate(1000,'Bangalore',30,9,'ABC')
```

Is there any better way of achieving the result as I expect?

Just fyi, tbl_3 will have max of 5 rows and tbl_2 can contain upto 3 for same pid. So, I wanted to show all the fields from three tables within 5 rows in single table for each pid. How can I do it?

Comment: You need select records from 3 tables? Why you trying to create procedure instead of simple SELECT with JOINs?

Comment: since i have same id(pid), i couldn't join simply...  if i do i get redundant rows from table 2 and 3

Comment: You should not be doing row by ro w updates ever. That is just a bad coding practice. This needs to be set-based as well as using joins.  If you get multiple rows that have different values you need to have business rules to determine which value is correct,.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I started off with joins and realized I couldn't do it for this requirement..  Is there any other way to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all of your code with the following SQL

```
 select *
 from tbl_1 t1 left join 
 (select ISNULL(t2.pid, t3.pid) as merge_pid, t2.sid, t2.nrt2, t3.wid, t3.nrt3
   from tbl_2 t2 full join tbl_3 t3 on t2.soid = t3.woid) as mrg_table
 on t1.pid = mrg_table.merge_pid
```

edit to provide a new approach below based on the requirement specified in chat:

> "What I am looking for is: 5 records for each pid in
>   tbl_sourcef, that should contain table1(row can be redundant for
>   single pid), table 2 and table 3 (rows from tbl_2 and tbl_3 shouldn't
>   repeat) in the tbl_sourcef table"

```
 select pid, loc, avaId, xpId, qf, sid, nrt2, wid, nrt3 
 from tbl_1,
 (select ZZZ.M_ID, t2.*, t3.* from
     (select 1 as M_ID union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5) ZZZ
 left join 
 (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by soid) ID1, pid as pid1, sid, nrt2 from tbl_2 ) t2
 on zzz.M_ID = t2.ID1 
 left join 
 (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by woid) ID2, pid as pid2, wid, nrt3 from tbl_3 ) t3
 on zzz.M_ID = t3.ID2) YYY
 where tbl_1.pid = ISNULL(YYY.pid1, YYY.pid2)
```

Comment: Hi Douglas, Thank you for it.. But I get error '
[Err] 1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'' ..am checking it

Comment: Since a simple query provides the data that is needed, would it be possible to just create a view (CREATE VIEW view_1 as select....) and completely forego the use of a stored procedure?

Comment: full join tbl_3, do you mean t2.pid=t3.pid ?? please note that 'pid' is the only reference for these three tables. soid and woid cannot be used as equal condition

Comment: but your comment doesn't match the result table you are expecting. why should the 1st row of tbl_sourcef have sid=1 and wid=2? what was special about those two rows that caused them to be joined?  Why join only those 2 rows? If you were joining on pid, then all rows would join with each other.

Comment: Sorry, if something has confused.. If you look into the SP, I used pid as condition not the soid and woid.. pid is the only id that will be same in all the three tables

Comment: No, if you look at your procedure, you will see that you ARE using soid and woid in the join: "select sid from tbl_2 where soid=si and pid=pid" alongside  "select wid from tbl_3 where woid=wii and pid=pid"  achieves the same result I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97679/discussion-between-douglas-timms-and-sathish-panduga).

Comment: OK - now that I unserstand the requirement a little more, I think this SQL will do the trick (see edited answer):

Comment: Thanks a lot Douglas for your time!.. I ran the query and I got a syntax error, checking it